# What is the name for the experiment where you experience a feeling of weightlessness while sitting on a chair?

Tags: perception

I've heard about an experiment with a very simple setup where you experience a feeling of weightlessness while sitting on a chair. I heard this on a podcast but I can't remember the details or the name of the phenomenon. I only remember that you do *something* or that *something* is done to you while you sit on a chair that gives you a surprisingly real feeling of weightlessness and that this something is a pretty simple procedure.

Comment: Which podcast? Can you link it for reference (you can edit your question)? Please provide the minimum amount of details as you heard on the podcast in order so we too understand what the experiment you are talking about is about.

Comment: The podcast I heard it on is http://crateandcrowbar.com which is a PC gaming podcast. The topic came up when they were discussing VR gaming but I don't remember the episode and there are hundreds of episodes. I only remember what I wrote in the OP. You do *something* or *something* is done to you while you sit on a chair and you end up feeling like you're floating.